# Action Script 3 return value from Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have AS3 class which parses xml and creates buttons foreach item in XML. However I want to access total number of items later.How can i do that ?

**I am using it like this.**

```
var menu:MenuClass = new MenuClass();
trace( menu.aItems() );
```

Right now it is retuning `NAN` however If i trace it after line `Items =  xml.item.length();` it outputs correct number.

```
package com.lib.menu
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class MenuClass extends MovieClip {

        private var urlLoader:URLLoader;
        private var urlRequest:URLRequest;
        private const XML_PATH:String = "resources/menu.xml";
        private var xml:XML;
        protected var Items:Number;

        public function MenuClass() {

            urlLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(XML_PATH));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
        }
        private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void 
        {
            xml = new XML(e.target.data);
            Items =  xml.item.length();
            for (var i:int = 0; i < Items; i++) {
                var btn:Button = new Button(xml.item[i].@title,xml.item[i].@image);
                btn.y = Math.floor(i * (btn.height+2)) ;
                addChild(btn);
            }
        }
        public function aItems():Number {
            return Items;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That is because when you access `aItems()`, your XML has not been loaded yet. So you need to change your way of accessing the number of items.

Comment: Exactly what putvande wrote you. Plus... do not use capital I in Items, it looks like a class...

Answer (score 3):

`URLLoader` loads data asynchronously which means the constructor `MenuClass` does not wait for the loading to complete. When loading of the XML is complete `xmlLoaded` will be called and a valid value will be set to `Items`. But you are trying to access `Items` just after creating the object, i.e. before `xmlLoaded` is called. So you are getting `NaN` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved this by adding `this.dispatchEvent(new Event("MenuComplete"));` to end of `private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void`  and then

```
var menu:MenuClass = new MenuClass();
menu.addEventListener('MenuComplete', onNext); 
function onNext(e:Event):void{
    trace(menu.aItems());
}
```